# Bind Observable to template using async

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable, angular-pipe

I'm trying to bind an Observable to a template variable in Angular by doing:

```
[class.active]="isBookmarked$ | async"
```

In the ngOnInit, I'm setting the Observable:

```
var promise = this.cacheService.getItem(this.bookmarkId).then(() => {
    return true;
}).then(() => {
    return false;
});
this.isBookmarked$ = Observable.fromPromise(promise);
```

Which works fine when I load the page. But when I add or remove an item, the template does not recognize the change detection.

```
this.cacheService.removeItem(this.bookmarkId).then(() => { });
// or
this.cacheService.saveItem(this.bookmarkId, true, "bookmarks").then(() => { });
```

I've tried different Observables and also tried a Promise without making it an Observable, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: _But when I add or remove an item, the template does not recognize the change detection._ are you using subjects? because the variable `this.isBookmarked` doesnt keep getting updates after the first one

Comment: No, I'm not using subjects. So basically what you're saying is that I need a shared subject so the isBookmarked Observable get's updated after you call removeItem/saveItem, right?

Comment: yes.. or you need to call getItem again somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since promises fire only once you won't be notified again. The only way will be to wrap cacheService into a new service (if you can't change the original) like this:

```ts
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import "rxjs/add/operator/filter";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

interface CacheService
{
    getItem(key: any): Promise<any>;

    setItem(key: any, value: any): Promise<any>;
}

interface Item
{
    key: any;
    value: any;
}

@Injectable()
export class ObservableCacheService
{
    protected readonly items$ = new Subject<Item>();

    constructor(protected readonly cacheService: CacheService) { }

    getItem(key: any)
    {
        this.cacheService
            .getItem(key)
            .then(value => items$.next({ key: key, value: value }));
        return items$
            .filter(item => item.key === key)
            .map(item => item.value);
    }

    setItem(key: any, value: any)
    {
        this.cacheService
            .setItem(key, value)
            .then(() => items$.next({ key: key, value: value }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the following example seems to work. Is that how you meant it? https://gist.github.com/erwinokken/d4c7a21fecb9781c7fb79e331ac61d64

Comment: yeah, something like this, but you didn't filter by bookmarkId - this way you will receive changes for all of them - not just what you specified in exists method.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed it after testing. I got it working now!